# How to inspect elements on an android device

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, inspect

Is there any way to inspect a website on android device. I'm not asking about `Ctrl+U` or view-source:https://blabla.com/, I'm asking about `Ctrl+Shift+I`.

Comment: https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-inspect-elements-on-Android-devices-using-Chrome

Answer (score 2):

What you are asking about is usually called **remote debugging**. While there are [many related questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=remote+debugging+is%3Aquestion) already, I was not able to find one that is not completely outdated.

First, you will need to install the [Android Debug Bridge (adb)](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb) on your computer.
Then set up remote debugging with your browsers.

- For Firefox, see [about:debugging](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/about:debugging#Connecting_over_the_Network).
- For Chrome, see [Remote Debugging Android Devices](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to inspect (Ctrl +Shift+ I) the html, There are mobile apps like website editor and other things. If you want to make it to css, better download yandex browser and go to chrome web store and add similar extensions like css inspector. Now open extension and hover the element you want to view.